# Output from node js console to Express js webpage

Tags: node.js, express

i have a console app, which connects to a server, prints output to the console.
here is the code made with Node js

```
var net = require('net');

var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(port, 'ip', function() {
    console.log('Connected');
    client.write('enter password...');
});

client.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('Received: ' + data);
    
});
```

i can login successfully and read the output sent by the server on console based application, but i want to see these outputs on webpage. i tried using express but i have no clue how to use it.

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    client.on('data', function(data) {
        res.send('<p>: ' + data + '</p>');
        
    });
});

can anyone tell me where i am wrong? or should i use something else?
```

Comment: "but i want to send these outputs to web." What?! Please clarify what you want. Edit your quesiton, and take a few seconds to complete the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour),  read ["How to Ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Looks like you have a missunderstanding how async/sync code execution works. (guessed from your express snippet)

Comment: i have updated my question, if you still cannot understand let me know.